# How to check the condition for data-target?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

Is it possible to write something like this in the more optimal way:

```
<li [ngClass]="sidebarVisible ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-item sidebar-false-new-folder'"
    *ngIf="sidebarVisible">
  <a (click)='this.createNewDirectory()' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler"
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i
    class="nc-icon nc-simple-add"></i>New Folder</a>
</li>

<li [ngClass]="sidebarVisible ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-item sidebar-false-new-folder'"
    *ngIf="!sidebarVisible">
  <a (click)='this.createNewDirectory();' data-toggle="collapse" 
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i
    class="nc-icon nc-simple-add"></i>New Folder</a>
</li>
```

The only different part is `data-target="#navbarToggler"`. I tried something like this:

```
<li [ngClass]="sidebarVisible ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-item sidebar-false-new-folder'">
  <a (click)='this.createNewDirectory()' data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="{{ sidebarVisible ? '#navbarToggler' : '' }}" 
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i
    class="nc-icon nc-simple-add"></i>New Folder</a>
</li>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<li [ngClass]="sidebarVisible ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-item sidebar-false-new-folder'">
  <a (click)='this.createNewDirectory()' data-toggle="collapse"  [attr.data-target]="sidebarVisible ? '#navbarToggler' : '' " 
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i
    class="nc-icon nc-simple-add"></i>New Folder</a>
</li>
```

Comment: `Can't bind to 'data-target' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. (")">
  <a (click)='this.createNewDirectory(); this.ExecuteWhenSidebarClose()' data-toggle="collapse" [ERROR ->][data-target]="sidebarVisible ? '#navbarToggler' : '' "
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDem")` Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok and with `[attr.data-target]`?

Comment: Cétia I am really sorry but I am afraid that not properly working sidebar doesn't depends only on `data-target="#navbarToggler"`. It seems to me that your solution with `[attr.data-target]` is good but I am not sure. However everything works properly in the example shown in my question with `*ngIf`. Do you think that this solution is acceptable from the point of view of the clean code. Or perhaps do you think that this solution absolutely shouldn't take place in good quality code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [ng-bootstrap collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples) ?

```
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```